# How to link a part of a file into another one?

Tags: linux

Is there any way to do something like the `ln` but for the part of a source (text) file?

I have two configuration files and I would want that a changes in certain part of one of them will be putted in certain place of another automatically.

Comment: You can't.  However, most configuration systems allow you to include other files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "link" a file into another, generally.

What you describe is the effect of using an "include statement", which when parsed by some parser is expanded to include the mentioned file, as in

```
#include "myheader.h"
```

in a C source code processed by a C pre-processor like `cpp`, or

```
include myrules.mk
```

in a (GNU) Makefile, or

```
.include myrules.mk
```

in a (BSD) Makefile, or

```
include(mymacros.m4)
```

in `m4`.

There are also templating systems that, when parsing a template, substitutes particular patterns found therein with data from variables or files.